# Disable Save and save as while downloading a file ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I'm creating a web page with a download option 
when the user clicks the the download option he gets three options

- Open
- Save
- Save As

I just want the user to see

- Open

I'm using ASP.NET 4

Thank You

p.s. i tried google but no good

Comment: I guess problem is, that when user clicks save as, it saves not what you indented, if that is so - solve this problem directly, not by disabling something in browser.

Comment: if it is disable it will work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, this would be a security risk. I think the next best thing is to have the user register an application to a uri scheme, this is something that needs to be configured on the client pc trough the registry. ( for windows )

Off course, this means your application needs to support this as well. You can see how that works here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

The best thing is to have this register when the application installs trough the installer, otherwise you can provide an executable to modify the registry, or do it manually on every client, or have the user download an executable from the site, which ever is feasible.

If you are developing the client application, you could go the other way and have it poll the webserver, but that is off course a more evolved solution.

Comment: So, it is not possible

Comment: Not with javascript or standard browser functionality, you could always resort to flash or java to get this to work.

Comment: what i have to add in the registry

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx , you will also have to change your links off course

Comment: so we have to do this for all the systems

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the file type you are serving, you may be able to add the following header to the response message:

```
content-disposition: inline
```

Code:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline")
```

This will tell the browser to open the file immediately instead of displaying the dialogue box.  But it will only work if the browser supports the file type.

Answer (score 0):

Save, Save As, Open are your browser's options. Check in different browsers and you will see different options. Hell, I could make a browser with "Hit", "Hit Me", "Hit Me Again" and "Take a Look" options. You cannot control them from your asp.net code.

The best you can do from your code is to instruct your browser to display the downloaded content inline or as an attachment using:

> Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=somefile.pdf")

or

> Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline")

The first option will trigger your browser's download options (in your case will show Save, Save As and Open buttons). In my case Chrome will automatically save the file without asking me anything.

The second option will directly open the file but ONLY if the browser will correctly identify the content-type of the downloaded content and if it CAN display it.

For example, for a PDF file you need to set:

> Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

and you need to have Acrobat Reader if you are using older browsers or you need to use a newer browser that already has a PDF plugin installed (IE7+, Chrome, etc...)

I hope this helps.